# Object.is equality check in react hook is causing multiple versions of the same function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm not sure what the correct fix is to stop the following scenario.  I've created [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-cancellable-fetch-ebcio) to highlight the problem.

I have this hook and here is a scaled down version:

```js
export const useAbortable = <T, R, N>(
  fn: () => Generator<Promise<T>, R, N>,
  options: Partial<UseAbortableOptions<N>> = {}
) => {
  const resolvedOptions = {
    ...DefaultAbortableOptions,
    ...options
  } as UseAbortableOptions<N>;
  const { initialData, onAbort } = resolvedOptions;
  const initialState = initialStateCreator<N>(initialData);
  const abortController = useRef<AbortController>(new AbortController());
  const counter = useRef(0);

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const runnable = useMemo(
    () =>
      makeRunnable({
        fn,
        options: { ...resolvedOptions, controller: abortController.current }
      }),
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    [counter.current]
  );

  const runner = useCallback(
    (...args: UnknownArgs) => {
      console.log(counter.current);

      dispatch(loading);

      runnable(...args)
        .then(result => {
          dispatch(success<N>(result));
        })
        .finally(() => {
          console.log("heree");
          counter.current++;
        });
    },
    [runnable]
  );

  return runner;
};
```

The hook takes a function and options object and as they are recreated on each render, and the hooks use `Object.is` comparison, it was creating a new version of the returned function no matter what I do.

So I have hacked it like this, to use a counter:

```js
  const runnable = useMemo(
    () =>
      makeRunnable({
        fn,
        options: { ...resolvedOptions, controller: abortController.current }
      }),
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    [counter.current]
  );
```

I have had to silence the linter to make this possible.

What the linter suggests is this:

```js
  const runnable = useMemo(
    () => makeRunnable({ fn, options: { ...resolvedOptions, controller: abortController.current } }),
    [fn, resolvedOptions],
  );
```

But `fn` and `resolvedOptions` are causing a new runnable function to be created each time.

It is a real pain having to wrap everything in `useCallback`, `useMemo`, and friends.

I've had a look at other fetch libraries and they are doing other things like this, like `JSON.stringify` dependency arrays to get around this problem.

I like hooks but the `Object.is` equality check is killing the whole paradigm.

What would be the correct way for me to use the dependency array correctly so I don't get a new function each time and also keep the linter happy?  The 2 requirements seem to add odds with each other.

Comment: `Can anyone highlight what dangers I could be running into with this approach.` runnable could be a function that has [stale closures](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts typescript

Comment: @dagda1, Thanks for your great question. I leave upvote to appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You must note that you need not provide any hack to get around the callback problem**

ESLint warnings about missing dependency are there to help users avoid mistakes make unknowingly and not to be enforced.

Now in your case

If you look at your `useAbortable` function, you are passing a `generator function` and `an options object`, now both of them are created on every re-render.

You can `memoize the options` and `function` passed to `useAbortable` to avoid issues with dependencies

- If you use `callback pattern for setMessages`, you can create `onAbort` once only by providing `[]` dependency to useCallback
- The generator function depends on a time delay from state so you can create it with useCallback and provide `delay` as a dependency

```
      const onAbort = useCallback(() => {
        setMessages(prevMessage => (["We have aborted", ...prevMessage]));
      }, []); // 


      const generator = useCallback(
        function*() {
          const outsideLoop = yield makeFetchRequest(delay, "outside");

          processResult(outsideLoop);

          try {
            for (const request of requests) {
              const result = yield makeFetchRequest(delay, `${request.toString()}`);

              processResult(result);
            }
          } catch (err) {
            if (err instanceof AbortError) {
              setMessages(["Aborted"]);
              return;
            }
            setMessages(["oh no we received an error", err.message]);
          }
        },
        [delay, processResult]
      );

      const options = useMemo(() => ({ onAbort }), [onAbort]);
      const { run, state, abortController, reset, counter, ...rest } = useAbortable<
        Expected,
        void,
        Expected
      >(generator, options);
```

Now inside `useAbortable` you need not worry about `fn` or `options` changing as they will only change when they absolutely have too if we implement it like above

So you your runnable instance in useAbortable can be clearly created with the correct dependencies

```
const resolvedOptions = useMemo(() => ({
    ...DefaultAbortableOptions,
    ...options
  }), [options]);

  const runnable = useMemo(
    () =>
      makeRunnable({
        fn,
        options: { ...resolvedOptions, controller: abortController.current }
      }),
    [fn, resolvedOptions]
  );
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-cancellable-fetch-1cxss?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: What is reason behind `processResult` as a dependency in the generator?

If I understand correctly, `processResult` will not change after the 1st render.

Comment: @UtsavPatel Its just to avoid warning and will not contribute anything to the final result since its only created once and will not change

Comment: Thanks for the info, I thought I am missing something.

Comment: :-) No you are not. Actually ESlint has been improved to not throw warning for state update callbacks but still throws warning for functions with useCallback created once. Now we can use our fruitful judgement to disable the warning but then it will be disabled for future changes too. So in such cases I feel its okay to follow the warning and update the code since we know it anyways its not going to change

Comment: Dear @ShubhamKhatri, can you take a lot to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61762517/6877799). is that my answer right? you are very professional, your ideas is important to me. thanks in advantage.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `resolvedOptions` and `fn` and not with `runnable`. You should rewrite `runnable` dependencies as the linter suggests and modify `resolvedOptions` to also be a memoized.

```js
// I assume that `DefaultAbortableOptions` is defined outside of the `useAbortable` hook
const resolvedOptions = useMemo(() => ({
  ...DefaultAbortableOptions,
  ...options
}), [options]};
```

> The hook takes a function and options object and as they are recreated on each render, and the hooks use Object.is comparison, it was creating a new version of the returned function no matter what I do.

When you consume your hook you should also pay attention to not recreate stuff unnecessarily and use `useMemo` and `useCallback` for data and functions defined inside your components.

```js
function MyComponent () {
  const runnable = useCallback(() => {}, [/*let the linter auto-fill this*/])
  const options = useMemo(() => ({}), [/*let the linter auto-fill this*/])
  const runner = useAbortable(runnable, options)
}
```

This way the `runner` function will only be recreated when it really needs to be (when the dynamic dependencies of `runnable` and `options` change).

You have to go all-in with hooks if you use them and really wrap everything in them to make things work without shady bugs. I personally dislike them because of these traits.

Extra note: as the [React docs point out](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo), `useMemo` is not guaranteed to run only when its dependencies change, it may run on any render and cause `runner` to be recreated. In the current version of React this does not happen but it may happen in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no need to wrap everything in `useCallback`, `useMemo` and etc.

About `useCallback` when it is necessary to use if we have an optimized child component and we pass an inside-function as a prop to it, then in each re-render, all variables and functions in the execution context of the function component are evaluated and re-created, so the child component mistakenly thinks the passed prop has changed but it doesn't have any changes it just re-created. so we use `useCallback` to memoize the inside-function and pass an array of dependency to really re-created it but it is obvious in each re-render JavaScript re-evaluated the function and it is inevitable.

And about the `useMemo`, you correctly use it for your case and this hook is for the memoizing variables in each re-render that it is needed to change on some dependencies, maybe these dependencies are not the things that the linter wants. you truly use your dependency, the `counter.current` for your desire.

The linter rule, hence [`react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-can-i-do-if-my-effect-dependencies-change-too-often) is set for the below sample:

```js
function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      setCount(count + 1); // This effect depends on the `count` state
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, []); // linter error: Obviously `count` is a dependency to this current useEffect

  return <h1>{count}</h1>;
}
```

So for having better use and omitting the dependency and have happy linter it is better to write the above code like the following:

```js
function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      setCount(c => c + 1); // This line doesn't depend on `count` variable outside
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, []); // happy linter: because there is no dependency

  return <h1>{count}</h1>;
}
```

As you see the `setCount` uses an internal option to read the current state and by passing a function instead of an expression omit the dependency. so it can be inspiring in your case, I suggest two solutions:

1. There is no difference between directly passing a function to `useMemo` or creating it by a function expression definition, so do it:

   ```js
   const runnableFunction = () =>
     makeRunnable({
       fn,
       options: { ...resolvedOptions, controller: abortController.current }
     });

   const runnable = useMemo(
     runnableFunction,
     [counter.current]
   );
   ```

   By using this hack JavaScript doesn't sense change and the linter is happy, also, your correct usage of hooks still remains too.
2. The `fn` comes from custom hook argument and the `resolvedOptions` made by `options` that comes from custom hook argument too and both of them maybe will have changes in the future. so by the emphasis of [ReactJS docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html) and the emphasis of [Dan Abramov](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6880#issuecomment-485912528), to use this rule pass the linter required dependencies **plus** your desired dependencies together:

   ```js
   const runnableFunction = () =>
     makeRunnable({
       fn,
       options: { ...resolvedOptions, controller: abortController.current }
     });

   const runnable = useMemo(
     runnableFunction,
     [counter.current, fn, resolvedOptions]
   );
   ```

   I guess it is better to pass your desired dependencies at first.

For your current case, I recommended using the first one, but if the question is generic I recommended the second solution. it is recommended by docs.

**Note**: if you use the second solution, be aware this is an optimized custom hook function, so when you using it anywhere, you should pass a memorized `fn` and `options` to it. just like docs guidance.

Comment: @AmerllicA Although this provides a lot of insight it does take into account that OPs fn and options variable will keep changing on each re-render. Now if you do not provide fn and options to dependency even though linter will be happy but you code will not behave correctly when a required dependency value within fn changes

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri, Thanks for your time. I leave an upvote to appreciate.

Comment: @BertalanMiklos, Thanks for your opinion, A new door is opened to me. really thanks. My mindset about rendering and re-rendering is changed now. I leave several upvotes to your post to appreciate.

Comment: Dear @BertalanMiklos, It is me who should thank you. I have trouble misunderstanding about some concepts.